# Successful GraphQL Mutation keeps Returning Undefined

Tags: react-native, graphql, mutation

I am sending a mutation over from a React Native Frontend to a NodeJs / GraphQL Backend. The mutation request goes through, and a mutation occurs, but back on the frontend, the value of that mutation is `undefined` when it should instead be returning an ID. My mutation looks like this...

```
export default {
    Mutation: {
        driverCreateCollisionAccident: async (_, {
            accidentId,
            specific_pictures,
            contact_info,
            collision_report,
            extra_info
        }, context) => {
            const driver = await checkDriverAuth(context)
            
            const foundAccident = await db.accident.findUnique({
                where: {
                    id: accidentId
                }
            })

            if (!foundAccident) {
                throw new Error("Accident does not exist")
            }

            await handleDriverAccidentOwnership(driver.id, accidentId)

            console.log("right before create collision mutation")
            try {
               
                return await db.collisionAccident.create({
                    data: {
                        specific_pictures: specific_pictures,
                        contact_info: contact_info,
                        collision_report: collision_report,
                        extra_info: extra_info,
                        accident: {
                            connect: {
                                id: accidentId
                            }
                        },
                        accidentId: accidentId                        
                    }
                }).then( (resolved) => {
                    console.log(resolved)
                    return resolved
                })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
                throw new Error(error)
            }


        }
    }
}
```

The most important part of that code is

```
.then( (resolved) => {
   console.log(resolved)
   return resolved
})
```

As the console.log returns exactly what it is supposed to, an object that looks like this...

```
  id: '81b7cc7c-53d7-43d7-bb14-1438ef53a227',
  specific_pictures: { 'Pic One': 'Test url' },
  contact_info: {
    address: 'Have Picture',
    lastname: 'Have Picture',
    firstname: 'Have Picture',
    phone_number: '123456789',
    insurance_provider: 'Have Picture',
    driver_license_number: 'Have Picture',
    insurance_policy_number: 'Have Picture'
  },
  extra_info: 'null',
  collision_report: {
    towed: true,
    legal_fault: 'I caused the accident',
    fire_or_explode: true
  },
  accidentId: '0b5fd832-9540-475e-9b34-ece6dfdc58df'
}
```

But for some reason, when I try to log the results of this mutation on the frontend, all I get is `undefined`, but no errors occur, and I still get the backend's console.logs to hit properly so the mutation itself is working. My front end code looks like this...

```
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        handleMutation().then(  (resolved) => {
            console.log(resolved)
        })
    }

    const handleMutation = async () => {
        await driverCreateCollisionAccident({
            variables: {
                accidentId: collisionData.accidentId,
                specific_pictures: collisionData.specific_pictures,
                contact_info: collisionData.contact_info,
                collision_report: collisionData.collision_report,
                extra_info: collisionData.extra_info,
            }
        })
    }
```

I don't even need the full object returned, I JUST need an ID. Does anyone see what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this

```
const result = await db.collisionAccident.create({
                    data: {
                        specific_pictures: specific_pictures,
                        contact_info: contact_info,
                        collision_report: collision_report,
                        extra_info: extra_info,
                        accident: {
                            connect: {
                                id: accidentId
                            }
                        },
                        accidentId: accidentId                        
                    }
                })

return result
```

instead of

```
return await db.collisionAccident.create({
                    data: {
                        specific_pictures: specific_pictures,
                        contact_info: contact_info,
                        collision_report: collision_report,
                        extra_info: extra_info,
                        accident: {
                            connect: {
                                id: accidentId
                            }
                        },
                        accidentId: accidentId                        
                    }
                }).then( (resolved) => {
                    console.log(resolved)
                    return resolved
                })
```

Comment: Unfortunately that gives me the same result